# Pandas column-wise chunking

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

I want to read a large data matrix (currently testing with 90*85000, later 150000*850000) and do some operations on the columns.

In order to speed up things I tried chunking. This drastically speeds up (~100x) the reading process, but since I have to concatenate the chunks for column wise operations, I am loosing all the speed up in later steps.

My questions:
 - Is there a way to chunk in the column dimension instead of the row dimension?
 - Is there an alternative approach to what I want to achieve?

\Edit: Some timed runs:

- read small file: ~10s
- read small file, with 'chunksize=20': <0.1 s
- read small file, with manually implemented column-wise chunking: ~50s
  w/o concatenation, ~4min w/ concatenation
- read file line by line with some post-processing equivalent to what pandas does ~13s

Comment: Are you using all 85000 columns? if not read only the columns you need "usecols".

Comment: @Merlin Since this is preprocessing step, unfortunately, the answer is yes

Comment: /@Dahlai What is the size of file on disk, and how much ram do have? With  out all the code can you outline data munge process..... Are you using IPython notebook?

Comment: Wow! `150000*850000` of 4-byte elements would require 475GB of RAM

Answer (score 0):

You can chunk both `columns` and `rows`:

```
def chunks(lst, chunksize):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), chunksize):
        yield lst[i:i+chunksize]

col_chunksize, row_chunksize = 1000, 1000
for use_cols in chunks(columns, col_chunksize):
    for chunk in pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=row_chunksize, use_cols=use_cols)
        process_chunk # e.g. pd.concat() to the process all rows of use_cols
```

Comment: I implemented a version like this. Unfortunately, the repeated 'pd.read_csv' calls turn out to be really slow, as is the subsequent concatenation. I'll edit my original question to give some numbers.

Comment: Probably need to optimize the chunksizes. If your `column` operations don't change the number/order of rows, you don't have to use `pd.concat`, you could just combine the underlying numpy arrays (containing all rows for subset of the columns) into a new DataFrame.

Comment: If I understand this correctly this would mean I'd loose the column labels? They are essential for my later work with the data

Comment: Not necessarily. You have the `column` labels already when you chunk the `columns`, so you can just reassign them to the `DataFrame` that contains the numpy arrays using `df.columns=columns`. You can also get the labels by just reading the first line of your file, of course, using `nrows=1`.

Comment: I tried a few things, also implementing concatenation using numpy matrices, which works, but the bottleneck remains. Calling 'pd.read_csv' frequently with different column subsets is slow...