# Techniques for working with very large Pandas data frames or csv files in Python

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a huge csv file (14gb) on disk that I need to "melt" (using pd.melt) - I can import the file using pd.read_csv() without issue, but when I apply the melt function I max out my 32gb of memory and hit a "memory error" limit. Can anyone suggest some solutions? The original file is the output of another script, therefore I cannot reduce it by only importing selected columns or removing rows. There are a few hundred columns and over 10 million rows.. I tried something like this (in a much abbreviated version):

```
chunks = pd.read_csv('file.csv', chunksize=10000)
ids = list(set(list(chunks.columns.values)) - set(['1','2','3','4','5']))

out = []
for chunk in chunks:
   df = pd.melt(chunk, id_vars=ids, var_name='foo',value_name='bar')
   df['a_col'] = df['a_col'].fillna('not_na')
   out.append(df)
full_df = pd.concat(out, ignore_index=False)
df_grouped = pd.DataFrame(full_df.groupby(['id_col', 'foo'])['bar'].apply(lambda x: ((x-min(x))/(max(x)-min(x))*100)))

df_grouped.columns = ['bar_grouped']
final_df = full_df.merge(df_grouped, how='inner' left_index=True, right_index=True)
final_df.to_csv('output.csv', sep='|', index=False)
```

Clearly this didn't work, as the columns.values attribute is not available for chunks since it is not a data frame. Any suggestions on how to re-code so it works and avoids memory issues are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you limited to use just a single machine? You could have a look at PySpark (python apis for a spark deployed app) or Dask.
Or, if you're inclined to change the approach, you could load your data in Mongo (just to name one) and run some aggregation pipelines (which are very efficient).

Comment: You can chunk by both rows and columns like in this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37727671/pandas-column-wise-chunking

Comment: @FrankBr I am limited for the moment, trying to get access to a PySpark node but that could take some time (big organisations tend to move slowly, and even more so when I'm up against a deadline it seems :)

Comment: And what about a MongoDB based solution? Seems you need to work with all the data at the same time and not applying some sort of mapping/reducing procedure to limit the amout of data loaded in memory. Thus, I'd give a try using Mongodb and its powerful aggregation framework.